# Could not import fmt.(or any other basic libs) VS Code Go Extension

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I recently installed go and the vscode go extension on my machine running Ubuntu 20.04. Everything works fine but there's one bug I cannot solve. When I create a new .go file I get the following error. However when I save the file, restart vscode, the error goes away and everything is fine.

[image]

The code I'm writing is a basic hello world program. Even when the error is there and I run `go run` or `go build` everything works fine. Its just an annoyance when creating a new file.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func foo() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}
```

If I run `echo $GOPATH` or `echo $GOROOT` in the terminal they both blank. Additionally when I run the `go env` command they defined as follow: `GOROOT="/usr/local/go"` and `GOPATH="/home/chadley/go"` (*chadley being username*)

I have changed nothing in the extension settings or any other environment variables.

Comment: Did you create a Go module in the root of your VScode workspace? The extension sometimes seems to have problems when no module is defined, so the question is if the error goes away after running something like `go mod init your.import/path`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comment provided by @[xarantolus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728357/xarantolus) solved the issue. Thanks a lot.

> Did you create a Go module in the root of your VScode workspace? The extension sometimes seems to have problems when no module is defined, so the question is if the error goes away after running something like go mod init your.import/path?

You can run these commands in your directory folder

```bash
go mod init
go mod tidy
```

This [page](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) also proved helpful for go modules

Comment: Well I think you deserve a medal for working out how go modules work from that page. I'm totally confused by it!

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem too. but it is because my go version is 1.19, and the go module requires 1.20, so I upgrade my go version to solve the problem.